# Parse detecting db changes

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse in my iOS App and was wondering if it had a way for my app to get notified when a db change is made.  I saw some outdated documentation that indicated there was a Parse.Cloud function but it does not seem to exist.

More recently I saw something about Parse.observeValue but cannot find any example of how to use it and I cannot seem to get it to work.

Does anyone in the Parse community know anything about this and maybe have a code snippet that shows how to perform such a function?

I have a table that keeps comments for users and I wanted to get notified when a comment is made.  For example, if user 1 adds a comment on their device I was hoping that user 2 could get a notification so the the app for user 2 could reload any new comments.

Hope this makes sense... as usual any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Parse provides [afterSave](http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#aftersave-triggers) triggers in cloud code.  Those, in conjunction with [push notifications](http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#push-notifications) would provide -- with a little latency -- a way to detect db change at the client.

If you really need this to work comprehensively and fast, I think the best alternative is [google firebase](https://firebase.google.com).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am currently using silent push notifications to do this.  I am familiar with firebase but it is too limiting for our needs.  I will look into afterSave, but for the time being our push notifications are working.  Thank you again for the reply!!!